# Proximal Operator of Huber Loss Function (For $ {L}_{1} $ Regularized Huber Loss of a Regression Function)

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, matlab, proximal-operators

I'm trying to derive the ADMM updates for the $\ell_1$ penalized Huber loss:

$$ \arg\min_x \phi_h \left(y - Ax\right) + \gamma\lVert x \rVert_1 $$

where

$$ \phi_h \left( u \right) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}u^2,  & \text{if } \mid u \mid \leq 1 \\
\mid u \mid - \frac{1}{2}, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

So far I know I need to compute the `prox` operator of both $ \phi_h $ and $ \lVert \rVert_1 $ and that the steps are:

$$ x^{k+1} = \arg \min_x \left(\phi_h\left(y-Ax\right) + \frac{\rho}{2}\lVert y - Ax -z^{k} + u^{k} \rVert \right) $$

$$ z^{k+1} = S_{\gamma/\rho}\left(x^{k+1} + u^{k+1} \right) $$

$$ u^{k+1} = u^{k} + x^{k+1} - z^{k+1}$$

where

$$ S_{\lambda}\left( y \right) = \mathrm{max} \left(y - \lambda, 0 \right) $$

This is from eqn 6.1. from [Distributed Optimization and Statistical Learning via the Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf):

I'm having difficulty finding the $x^{k+1}$ step. Boyd (section 6.1.1) suggests that it will be:

$$ \frac{\rho}{1+\rho}\left(Ax - y + u^k\right) + \frac{1}{1+\rho}S_{1+1/\rho}\left( Ax - y + u^k \right) $$

But the answers to [Proximal Operator of the Huber Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1650411/proximal-operator-to-huber-function) suggests the $j^{th}$ component of the `prox` operator will be:

$$ v_j = \frac{y_j-a_j x_j}{max\left(\mid y_j-a_j x_j \mid, 2 \right)} $$

Any help finding this would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: @dohmatob might find this question interesting

Comment: Introduce two variable splittings: $z = y - Ax$ and $w = x$, to obtain the Lagrangian $\mathcal L(x, z, w, u, v)  = \phi_h(z) + \gamma\|w\|_1 + \langle u, y - Ax - z\rangle + \frac{1}{2}\rho\|y-Ax-z\|_2^2 + \langle v, x - w\rangle + \frac{1}{2}\rho \|x-w\|_2^2$. Now (cyclically) fix 3 of the variables and optimize w.r.t the 4th.

Comment: ... All the proximal operators should now be simple to compute.

Comment: BTW, you problem looks like a natural candidate for primal-dual algorithms https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00490826/document

Comment: I'd be tempted to use FISTA to solve this problem, since the objective function has the form $f+g$, where $f$ is differentiable and $g$ is "simple" (meaning that $g$ has an easy prox-operator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Huber Loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss) is defined as:

$$ L_\delta \left( x \right) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} {x}^{2}                            & \text{for} \; \left| x \right| \leq \delta \\
\delta (\left| x \right| - \frac{1}{2} \delta) & \text{for} \; \left| x \right| > \delta
\end{cases} $$

For the case the input is a vector the Huber Loss is applied component wise and then all results are summed.

Regarding your question about the difference between derivations of the Proximal Operator for the Huber Loss.
I actually implemented both derivations of the Proximal Operator for the [Huber Loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss) $ {L}_{1} \left( \cdot \right) $ with $ \delta = 1 $ (To match your definition):

1. $ {\left( \operatorname{prxo}_{ \lambda {L}_{1} \left( \cdot \right) } \left( y \right) \right)}_{i} = {y}_{i} - \frac{\lambda {y}_{i}}{\max \left( \left| {y}_{i} \right|, \lambda + 1 \right)} $ from [Proximal Operator of the Huber Loss Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1650411).
2. $ \operatorname{prxo}_{ \lambda {L}_{1} \left( \cdot \right) } \left( y \right) = \frac{1}{1 + \lambda} y + \frac{\lambda}{1 + \lambda} \mathcal{S}_{1 + \lambda} \left( y \right) $ where $ \mathcal{S}_{\lambda} \left( \cdot \right) $ is the Soft Threshold Operator ([The Proximal Opertaor of the $ {L}_{1} $ Norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1961888)). This was taken from [Stephen Boyd, Neal Parikh, Eric Chu, Borja Peleato, Jonathan Eckstein - Distributed Optimization and Statistical Learning via the Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf) from the section called [Huber Fitting](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf#page=43). While in the book they use $ \rho = \frac{1}{\lambda} $ notation for the Proximal Operator. Hence I adapted it accordingly.

In my code I found both to be equivalent and accurate as I compared them to CVX.
The code is available at my [StackExchange Mathematics Q2791227 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/tree/master/Mathematics/Q2791227). The code is extended to support any value of $ \delta $ as in my solution to [Proximal Operator / Proximal Mapping of the Huber Loss Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3589025).

Pay attention that the book [Distributed Optimization and Statistical Learning via the Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf) use the Huber Loss Function for Robust Regression while you're using it for Regularized Robust Regression. Probably you need to adapt $ \lambda $ in your steps.