# Vectorizing Huber Loss function

Tags: convex-optimization, matrix-equations, python, vectorization

I have the following system to minimize with respect to **$\beta$** ($\phi$ and $\mathrm{y}$ are known) using Huber loss

$
\mathrm{argmin}_{\beta\in R^2}(\phi\beta-\mathrm{y}) 
$

where, for example,

$ 
\phi\beta-\mathrm{y} = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(0) & \sin(0) \\
  \cos(1) & \sin(1) \\
  \cos(2) & \sin(2)
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \beta_{0c} & \beta_{1c} & \beta_{2c} \\
  \beta_{0s} & \beta_{1s} & \beta_{2s} \\
 \end{bmatrix}-
 \begin{bmatrix}
  y_1 & y_2 & y_3 \\
  y_4 & y_5 & y_6 \\
  y_7 & y_8 & y_9
 \end{bmatrix} = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(0)\beta_{0c}+\sin(0)\beta_{0s}-y_1 & \cos(0)\beta_{1c}+\sin(0)\beta_{1s}-y_2 & \cos(0)\beta_{2c}+\sin(0)\beta_{2s}-y_3 \\ 
  \cos(1)\beta_{0c}+\sin(1)\beta{0s}-y_4 & \cos(1)\beta_{1c}+\sin(1)\beta_{1s}-y_5 & \cos(1)\beta_{2c}+\sin(1)\beta_{2s}-y_6 \\
  \cos(2)\beta_{0c}+\sin(2)\beta_{0s}-y_7 & \cos(2)\beta_{1c}+\sin(2)\beta_{1s}-y_8 & \cos(2)\beta_{2c}+\sin(2)\beta_{2s}-y_9
 \end{bmatrix}
$

Huber loss is defined as

$
 \gamma_\zeta(x) = 
 \begin{cases}
  \dfrac{1}{2}x       & |x| \leq \zeta \\
  \zeta|x|-\dfrac{1}{2}\zeta^2  & |x| > \zeta
 \end{cases}
$

**Problem Description:**

I would like to know how to vectorize the function. I'm confused what the value of $\mathrm{x}$ should be. In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2791227/proximal-operator-of-huber-loss-function-for-l-1-regularized-huber-loss) the answer mentions that **"the input is a vector the Huber Loss is applied component wise and then all results are summed"** but it doesn't really describe that part.

I think that's what I need to do, but not sure what it means. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What this basically means is that if you have a vector input $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$, then $f(x) = \gamma(x_1) + \gamma(x_2) + \gamma(x_3)$ where $\gamma$ is the scalar function you listed.

Comment: @Y.S.  Thank you for your help! I think you should have made that an answer instead of a comment

Comment: Using the _all-ones_ vector ${\tt1}$ to translate the quoted description into a mathematical equation  is straightforward  $\;f(x) = {\tt1}^T\gamma(x)\quad$